# Check dropped nodes

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

I have a NN model with `Dropout` layers. I'd like to check which nodes of the network have been dropped at each iteration. Or, which weights have been set to 0.

I tried looking at the model weights after one iteration, but it didn't contain any zeros, presumably because the dropped nodes don't transfer to the final model.

This question has been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49630178), but it didn't get an answer.

Comment: I answered a similar question some time ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54244630/in-keras-on-which-weight-is-the-dropout-applied/54244877#54244877

Comment: TLDR: There isn't a good way unless you modify the source, the zeroing is applied immediately and isn't saved

Comment: Dropout does not set any weight to zero, that is DropConnect.

Comment: An answer to this question was provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57881607), using `K.function`.